# Recover project from vmdk file

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, recover, vmdk

I want to recover project from vmdk file, am using vmware and it has catalina installed on it.
After restarting the vmware i was not able to open catalina again it keep saying macos 15.5.0 not installed on this device. I don't understand why it says macos 15.5.0 not installed on this device while i was using it for long time.
I really need help here, how to recover project from vmdk file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recover my data using paragon apfs for windows.
Link: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/#